# some questions on Lindelöf property

Tags: gn.general-topology

I have several questions on Lindelöf property.

If every point countable open cover of $X$ has a countable subcover (**Condition A**), does $X$ have Lindelöf property? How far is having **Condition A** from Lindelöf property?

**A space $X$ is called $\omega_1$-Lindelöf if every $\omega_1$-sized open cover of $X$ contains a countable subcover.**

Can every $\omega_1$-Lindelöf space with **Condition A**  be Lindelöf?

**A space $X$ is called discretely Lindelöf if the closure of every discrete subspace of $X$ is Lindelöf.**

Can every discretely Lindelöf space with **Condition A**  be Lindelöf?

Comment: The name is Lindelöf, not Lindeloff.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A space is Lindelöf iff it satisfies condition A and is metaLindelöf (every open cover has a point-countable refinement), so one could say the difference is metaLindelöfness.

Answer (score 1):

$X = \langle \omega_1,2^{\omega_1} \rangle$

The set of singleton subsets of $\omega_1$ is a point countable $\omega_1$-sized

open cover of $X$ that does not have a countable subcover.

I don't know the answers to your other two questions.

Comment: What's the topology on $X$?

Comment: The discrete topology (which is why the second entry in the ordered pair is the set of all subsets of $\omega_1$).

Comment: OK, you explained it.  To me, $2^{\omega_1}$ is a certain calculation in ordinal arithmetic...  For your example, I would say: a set of power $\aleph_1$ with discrete topology.  That way, I even avoid confusing ordinals with cardinals.